# Error building Ada Web Server (AWS) on OS X El Capitan

Tags: ada, gnat

I am trying to build AWS from git tree:

```
$ git clone --recursive http://forge.open-do.org/anonscm/git/aws/aws.git
```

and I have the following errors:

```
$ make setup build
gprbind xoscons.bexch
gnatbind xoscons.ali
gcc -c b__xoscons.adb
gcc xoscons.o -o xoscons
Setup OS specific definitions
aws-os_lib-tmplt.c:77:20: fatal error: stdlib.h: No such file or directory
 #include <stdlib.h>
                    ^
compilation terminated.
Can not generate system tags. The test are disabled
object directory "/Users/adrian/Desktop/aws/tools/../.build/x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0/release/static/obj/tools/" created
object directory "/users/adrian/desktop/aws/include/zlib/../../.build/x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0/release/static/obj/zlib" created for project zlib
library directory "/users/adrian/desktop/aws/include/zlib/../../.build/x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0/release/static/lib/zlib" created for project zlib
object directory "/users/adrian/desktop/aws/include/../.build/x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0/release/static/obj/include" created for project include
library directory "/users/adrian/desktop/aws/include/../.build/x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0/release/static/lib/include" created for project include
object directory "/users/adrian/desktop/aws/ssl/../.build/x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0/release/static/obj/ssl" created for project ssl
library directory "/users/adrian/desktop/aws/ssl/../.build/x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0/release/static/lib/ssl" created for project ssl
object directory "/users/adrian/desktop/aws/src/../.build/x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0/release/static/obj/src" created for project src
library directory "/users/adrian/desktop/aws/src/../.build/x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0/release/static/lib/src" created for project src
library directory "/Users/adrian/Desktop/aws/.build/x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0/release/static/lib/aws" created for project aws
exec directory "/Users/adrian/Desktop/aws/tools/../.build/x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0/release/static/tools" created for project tools
gcc -c -gnat2012 -gnatwcfijkmRuv -gnaty3abBcdefhiIklmnoOprstx -O2 -gnatn -fno-common awsres.adb
gcc -c -gnat2012 -gnatwcfijkmRuv -gnaty3abBcdefhiIklmnoOprstx -O2 -gnatn -fno-common aws_password.adb
gcc -c -gnat2012 -gnatwcfijkmRuv -gnaty3abBcdefhiIklmnoOprstx -O2 -gnatn -fno-common templates2ada.adb
gcc -c -gnat2012 -gnatwcfijkmRuv -gnaty3abBcdefhiIklmnoOprstx -O2 -gnatn -fno-common webxref.adb
gcc -c -gnat2012 -gnatwcfijkmRuv -gnaty3abBcdefhiIklmnoOprstx -O2 -gnatn -fno-common templatespp.adb
gcc -c -gnat2012 -gnatwcfijkmRuv -gnaty3abBcdefhiIklmnoOprstx -O2 -gnatn -fno-common wsdl2aws.adb
gcc -c -gnat2012 -O2 -gnatws -gnatn -fno-common zlib.adb
gcc -c -gnat2012 -O2 -gnatws -gnatn -fno-common zlib-thin.adb
gcc -c -gnat2012 -O2 -gnatws -gnatn -fno-common zlib-streams.adb
gcc -c -gnat2012 -O2 -gnatws -gnatn -fno-common memory_streams.adb
gcc -c -gnat2012 -gnatwcfijkmRuv -gnaty3abBcdefhiIklmnoOprstx -O2 -gnatn -fno-common templates_parser-xml.adb
gcc -c -gnat2012 -gnatwcfijkmRuv -gnaty3abBcdefhiIklmnoOprstx -O2 -gnatn -fno-common soap.ads
gcc -c -gnat2012 -gnatwcfijkmRuv -gnaty3abBcdefhiIklmnoOprstx -O2 -gnatn -fno-common soap-xml.adb
gcc -c -gnat2012 -gnatwcfijkmRuv -gnaty3abBcdefhiIklmnoOprstx -O2 -gnatn -fno-common soap-wsdl.adb
gcc -c -gnat2012 -gnatwcfijkmRuv -gnaty3abBcdefhiIklmnoOprstx -O2 -gnatn -fno-common soap-wsdl-types.adb
aws-os_lib.ads:30:01: cannot compile configuration pragmas with gcc
aws-os_lib.ads:30:01: use gnatchop -c to process configuration pragmas
compilation abandoned
soap-xml.adb:32:14: warning: license of withed unit "DOM.Core.Nodes" may be inconsistent
soap-xml.ads:34:09: warning: license of withed unit "DOM.Core" may be inconsistent
soap-wsdl.adb:35:09: warning: license of withed unit "DOM.Readers" may be inconsistent
soap-wsdl.adb:36:19: warning: license of withed unit "Input_Sources.File" may be inconsistent
soap-wsdl.adb:37:09: warning: license of withed unit "Sax.Readers" may be inconsistent
soap-wsdl.ads:32:09: warning: license of withed unit "DOM.Core" may be inconsistent
templates_parser-xml.adb:33:14: warning: license of withed unit "DOM.Core.Nodes" may be inconsistent
templates_parser-xml.adb:34:09: warning: license of withed unit "DOM.Readers" may be inconsistent
templates_parser-xml.adb:35:19: warning: license of withed unit "Input_Sources.File" may be inconsistent
templates_parser-xml.adb:36:19: warning: license of withed unit "Input_Sources.Strings" may be inconsistent
templates_parser-xml.adb:37:09: warning: license of withed unit "Sax.Readers" may be inconsistent
templates_parser-xml.adb:38:17: warning: license of withed unit "Unicode.CES.Basic_8bit" may be inconsistent
templates_parser-xml.adb:39:17: warning: license of withed unit "Unicode.CES.Utf8" may be inconsistent

   compilation of awsres.adb failed

gprbuild: *** compilation phase failed
make: *** [build-native] Error 4
```

A package downloaded from Libre (aws-gpl-2015) stopped building at aws-os_lib.ads.

Any pointers to get this going? I have read successful build of AWS package from Libre on OS X Maverick.

Should I use the git tree or the package from Libre?

I am running GNAT GPL 2015 (20150428-49) on El Capitan 10.11.2.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`aws-os_lib.ads` is a file that is generated from the C file where your log shows an error..., so perhaps it was not correctly generated in your case ?

Have you installed the xcode command line tools ?

```
xcode-select --install
```

Comment: It's working perfectly. Thanks. Have been away from Ada development for quite sometime and I forgot that I did a clean installation of El Capitan and Xcode. Thanks.

Comment: Actually, whether it's an install from scratch or an upgrade from an older version, OSX wipes out the command line tools, and you need to reinstall in both cases.